# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" rendering large dot file with d3-graphviz

Tags: d3.js, graphviz

If I `fetch` my ~800KB dotfile and try to process it with `graphviz.renderDot` in a manner similar to https://bl.ocks.org/magjac/4acffdb3afbc4f71b448a210b5060bca, then even after increasing the stack size with `.totalMemory(Math.pow(2, 27))`, I get the following message:

```
v Uncaught Maximum call stack size exceeded
  worker.onmessage @ d3-graphviz.js:1023
```

The single stack entry seems like the real stack is caught (and stack trace lost) elsewhere. I tried `Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity`, but that seems to do nothing. Is there a way to figure it out from the source of the message to the worker?

I have a local Git copy of the repo, but cannot seem to figure out how to build the target with local edits, e.g., to line 1906 of `d3-graphvis.js` v2.1.0, to not catch the error happening in the worker.

I'm a BE developer fumbling around in an FE world, so apologies in advance.

Comment: I tried using `useWorker` as `false`, but then got:

`d3-graphviz.js:796 Uncaught TypeError: Viz is not a function
    at Graphviz.initViz (d3-graphviz.js:796)
    at new Graphviz (d3-graphviz.js:1931)
    at Selection.selection_graphviz [as graphviz] (d3-graphviz.js:1974)
    at render_me.html:15`

Comment: Made https://bl.ocks.org/Capstan/a3279ce28fbe2dffa6219847f2761fd4 to illustrate the basic logic in use (with a different, larger file).

Comment: Have you tried to paste your large dot file at http://viz-js.com/?
It usually gives good error messages.
Regarding the case with useWorker=false: can you provide a complete test case? Here's one that works: https://bl.ocks.org/magjac/bf9659ab3117e274bdd0404fd83fdc2a

Comment: To build locally: `npm run build`

Comment: I had not, but doing so causes the OOM I worked around in my own sample: `Cannot enlarge memory arrays.`

Answer (score 0):

It works with Firefox Quantum 60.0.1 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (running in a VirtualBox 4.13.0-41-generic under Windows 7). See https://bl.ocks.org/magjac/704d486e783cf1d4a1e69ed4d33a1797 (the OP sent me the problematic DOT by email).

The OP was using Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E202